# Stuck. AddeventListener won't proccess my method inside my property. Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, addeventlistener

So i'm trying to do a simple test to see if addEventListener can reach a method inside my object.. So far, no bueno. Can anyone help and explain the reason why? From what i understand,  when i click, it's looking for that method in the DOM. I tried using bind but nothing happens. Doing it this way, at least i get an error. Guess i am not linking it correctly? 
HELP Please :(

```
The Error ----> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function     testing.js:12
               (anonymous function)


var userOne = function(){
    this.go = function(){
        alert("hello");
    };
}

unction getEle(what){
return document.getElementById(what);
}
function eventClick(id,func){
    return getEle(id).addEventListener("click", func);
}

eventClick("starter",function(){userOne.go();}); //is line 12
```

Comment: What's at testing.js:12? What is `getEle`? You realize that `this.go = ...` requires you call `new userOne`, right? There is not enough to debug your code for you (which isn't even what SO is for).

Comment: How is `getEle` defined? And yeah, `userOne` doesn't have a `go` property, so no surprise here. I'd recommend to read the MDN JavaScript guide to learn more about objects and constructor functions first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @FelixKling so you're saying that i need to create a new object using USerOne as a constructor so i could run that code?

Comment: That's how you wrote the code (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function). You could also use directly create an object: `var userOne = {go: ... };`

Comment: That won't be sufficient, you need to remove the parentheses from go() or it will execute the alert when the event handler is being assigned as opposed to when the event fires.

Comment: Correction, you're right, I'm wrong.  I got so caught up on the unnecessary anonymous function, that I forgot that it was still a function reference.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the function reference and not call it

`eventClick("starter",function(){return userOne.go;});`

Note the addition of the return statement and removal of the parentheses. Or

`eventClick("starter",userOne.go);`

Your parenthesis call the function, without it, you get a reference to the function.

Edit:

userOne is created as a constructor function, so you need two more changes:

`

```
var UserOne = function(){
    this.go = function(){
        alert("hello");
    };
}

var userOne = new UserOne();
```

`

Comment: Why should the OP return the function from the event handler? Also, `userOne` doesn't have a property `go`.

Comment: eventClick expects it's second argument to be a function.   so, a function needs to be passed in.  However, you're correct, userOne is a constructor function, so a variable needs to be instantiated.

Comment: *"eventClick expects it's second argument to be a function"* Exactly, and `function(){ ... }` is a function.

Comment: but so is userOne.go, once an instance is created. don't need the additional wrapper for it.

Comment: Sure, but if `userOne.go` is not called, like you suggest (`function(){return userOne.go;}`), then it will never be called.